# Does C# have an equivalent to decltype in C++11?

Tags: c#, c++, c++11, typeof, decltype

Being already familiar with C++ and after trying some of the new features C++11 offers, I decided to become more familiar with C#.

As expected, programming principles are similar, but some of the features are different. The differences and similarities are what I am looking after and therefore I decided to ask if C# has an equivalent to **decltype** in C++11?

```
int x = 4;
decltype(x) y = 16;
```

In the example above 'var' would work just fine, so here is an example of when decltype is needed. If I only conditionally call a function then I need to declare the variable that will hold its result without using 'var', as shown here:

```
var pendingProcessData = trace.UseProcesses();
// Only request CPU scheduling data when it is actually needed, to avoid
// unecessary trace processing costs. Unfortunately this means that the
// 
IPendingResult<ICpuSchedulingDataSource> pendingSchedulingData = null;
if (showCPUUsage)
    pendingSchedulingData = trace.UseCpuSchedulingData();

trace.Process();

ICpuSchedulingDataSource schedulingData = null;
if (showCPUUsage)
    schedulingData = pendingSchedulingData.Result;
```

With decltype I could say something like this:

```
var pendingProcessData = trace.UseProcesses();
// Only request CPU scheduling data when it is actually needed, to avoid
// unecessary trace processing costs. Unfortunately this means that the
// 
decltype(trace.UseCpuSchedulingData()) pendingSchedulingData = null;
if (showCPUUsage)
    pendingSchedulingData = trace.UseCpuSchedulingData();

trace.Process();

decltype(pendingSchedulingData.Result) schedulingData = null;
if (showCPUUsage)
    schedulingData = pendingSchedulingData.Result;
```

This extends the awesomeness of 'var' and would have saved me from tracking down what the concrete types are. To be clear, I *don't care* what the types of pendingSchedulingData and schedulingData are so forcing me to figure that out and mention it in the code has real cost but no value.

Comment: I don't think so. You could do it with losing the type information via reflection, but I don't think you can keep the known type without typing it again.

Comment: You know `decltype` is mostly for `template`s, and that's one of the areas where they strongly differ, as C# has far weaker facilities there?

Comment: Weaker? Nope. Different? Sure. C# has *generics*, which look like C++ *templates* but are a different mechanism. The feature sets overlap though.

Comment: @Lucas Trzesniewski One of the differences I've heard is that in C# generics can also be executed at runtime, whereas in C++ I can't think of any case in which you could execute templates at runtime.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I think the idea is that templates can do everything generics can, whereas generics cannot do everything templates can, so generics are weaker than templates. Not that that's not entirely true. There is one big thing generics do well that templates don't: distribute a generic function in object form and let an external caller instantiate it.

Comment: @hvd that is only true at turing tar pit levels: inheritance style type erasure using generics is so much less verbose in generics it is not funny.  Writing a container that allows implicit read only access with O(1) cast cost to a container of parent types, and similar write only to container of parent, is a pain in C++.  Doable, but a pain.  And if things are painful enough, they become 'why bother'.

Comment: `write only to container of parent` That would break the strong type system of C++…

Comment: @hvd generics are reified at runtime instead of compile time, and they have covariance/contravariance. These features are unavailable with C++ templates. So templates can't do everything generics can.

Comment: @Yakk Sure, that's another fair point. I should have written "There is at least one big thing"; I hadn't intended to imply that what I wrote was the only thing generics can do that templates cannot. I was attempting to clarify why one might feel that generics are strictly weaker, and then give a counterexample; I agree with Lucas Trzesniewski's comment that generics and templates are simply different.

Comment: @lucastrzesniewski covariance and contravariance can be implemented in templates.  See `std::function` and how it behaves based on input/output arguments to the signature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C# there's no equivalent to `decltype`.

Maybe type inference would be the nearest feature to `decltype`:

```
int x = 4;
var y = x + 1;
```

But there's no actual syntax feature that would allow to declare a storngly-typed variable with the type inferred from other given variable or expression.

Comment: Hmm, type inference would be the equivalent of `auto` / `decltype(auto)`.

Comment: @T.C. Well, check that I said "the nearest"... the actual answer is *no*

Comment: I was already familiar with automatic type inference in C#. C++11 also has this feature, but you have to use auto instead of var.

Comment: You might want to add what `decltype` is useful for, and why that's not relevant in C#.

Comment: @NewbornInYah BTW, there's no such feature in C#.

Comment: @Deduplicator Sadly my curiosity has proven me that I shouldn't answer C++ related answers, because I could answer it doing a quick research and learning what's `decltype` to determine if there's such feature in C#. But I'm not a C++ developer. I want to stay honest. If you want to edit my question to add that suggested info, or you want to add your own answer expanding my answer...

Comment: "In C# there's no equivalent to decltype." Alright, but why is that? Is it because C# has other features by which you can work out better, therefore making decltype equivalent not worth having it's participation in C#?

Comment: @NewbornInYah I believe I'll need to drop my answer, because I thought you wanted a "yes/no" answer, and this is why I took the risk of researching what `decltype` is and determining that there's no equivalent operator in C#.

Comment: @Matías Fidemraizer No need to at this point. Unless proven otherwise, leave this answer as it is. I decided to make this question short to answer and as a reference to those people wondering the same thing I do. :-)

Comment: @NewbornInYah Maybe you can tell me what you want to achieve in C# and I can give you a more accurate answer..

Comment: The short and the long of it is that [C# generics are far weaker than C++ templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cyy67b.aspx), and thus there is no need for `decltype`.

Comment: @NewbornInYah At this point, I need to go to bed! Feel free to leave me a comment with a small description of what you want to achieve in C# that should require `decltype` and I feel I might be able to give you some guidance. I hope that this answer has been useful for you ;)

Comment: Sometimes I want to write `e.ErrorCode == (decltype(e.ErrorCode))0x80072030` in C#.